# how do start/stop services using net stop command in c#

Tags: c#, process

how do start/stop services using net stop command in c#
for example

```
Dim pstart As New ProcessStartInfo
Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
Dim p As New Process
pstart.FileName = path + "\cmd.exe"
pstart.UseShellExecute = False
pstart.CreateNoWindow = True
pstart.WorkingDirectory = path
pstart.FileName = "cmd.exe"
pstart.Arguments = " net start mysql"
p.StartInfo = pstart
p.Start()
```

i have used process class but no result

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of using a crude method like Process.Start, you can use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(VS.80).aspx) class to start/stop a particular service on a local/remote machine.

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
ServiceController controller  = new ServiceController();

controller.MachineName = ".";
controller.ServiceName = "mysql";

// Start the service
controller.Start();

// Stop the service
controller.Stop();
```

Comment: I totally wrote this, too, and it didn't show the "new answers" thing before I posted. Good job!

Comment: You will need to add a reference to System.ServiceProcess too.

Comment: This will not work unless running with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a look at the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class, which provides a managed interface to Windows' Services.

In this case:

```
var mysql = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("mysql");
if (mysql .Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) {
   mysql.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 to you too. And btw, the "New Answers" thing polls every one minute, so it might have missed :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the "/c" switch to cmd.exe

```
pstart.Arguments = "/c net start mysql"
```