# How does one start and stop services using WMI from .NET?

Tags: .net, wmi, wmi-service

How would one go about using WMI to start, stop, and query services on the local computer from .NET code? (I'm using C#)

I have found [good and accurate answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113000/how-do-start-stop-services-using-net-stop-command-in-c) for using the ServiceController class to do this, but I'd like to use WMI if I can.

Comment: *Can* WMI do this? Is there an issue with using the ServiceController class? Certainly WMI can tell you about a service in terms of being an executing process- and from there you could start()/terminate() the process, but this seems like you're skipping a perfectly obvious layer of abstraction by choosing not to use the ServiceController class. Note: Please correct me if I'm horribly wrong here!

Comment: @nathan-taylor, you're right, ServiceController is much cleaner, I might switch to that at a later stage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to use WMI over the more intuitive `ServiceController` class, see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WMI_Services_Manipulation.aspx) (excuse the color scheme, but it has what you want).

Sample code (error handling here is bit hard-coded for my taste):

```
using System.Management;

public static ReturnValue StartService(string svcName)
{
    string objPath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name='{0}'", svcName);
    using (ManagementObject service = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(objPath)))
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = service.InvokeMethod("StartService",
                null, null);
            return (ReturnValue)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReturnValue),
            outParams["ReturnValue"].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.ToLower().Trim() == "not found" || 
                ex.GetHashCode() == 41149443)
                return ReturnValue.ServiceNotFound;
            else
                throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, that code on CodeProject does exactly what I asked for.