# How to start apache and mysql services programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, apache

I have develop a program that has a database and uses MySql
but I want it to be a user-friendly because every time you start the program. 
You would need to launch the xampp control panel and start those services

I dont like it because if someone couldn't start it, the program would not work properly. That's not user-friendly

So I would like to make it user-friendly when the Splash screen starts it will automatically start those services from background.

I've search over the internet but I couldn't find the right one 
Although, I tried this one and it starts the apache but it stucks on the command line like printing 'apache starting' and stuck on it. although the apache starts.

This is the code I have tested:

```
ProcessStartInfo apa = new ProcessStartInfo();
apa.Verb = "runas";
apa.CreateNoWindow = false;
apa.UseShellExecute = false;
apa.FileName = "c:\\xampp\\apache_start.bat";
apa.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(apa))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}

Thanks pal. All I need is to help me to start that APACHE and MYSQL services without using xampp  .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ServiceController`

```
ServiceController apache = new ServiceController("<your service name here>");
    if (apache.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped){
       apache.Start();
    }
```

similar for MySQL

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
ServiceController controller  = new ServiceController();

controller.MachineName = ".";
controller.ServiceName = "mysql";

// Start the service
controller.Start();

// Stop the service
controller.Stop();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113000/how-do-start-stop-services-using-net-stop-command-in-c-sharp)

Comment: thx for the dupe call out. Which should have been a comment and not just a copy of their code over here. Cheers.