# Start MySql Services using C# Pro grammatically

Tags: c#, service

To start Wamp Server i am using following code.

```
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("wampmanager");
if (pname.Length == 0)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\wamp\wampmanager");
    Thread.Sleep(700);
}
```

Now , actually i want to Check MySql Service. If already it is not running, start it.

I found answer nearest to my question
[how do start/stop services using net stop command in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113000/how-do-start-stop-services-using-net-stop-command-in-c-sharp)
But in my case, I found message MySql service is not found on machine.

Comment: What is your core question? How to detect if a service is avaiable? How to start it? Why you can't start MySQL on your machine?

Comment: @Link , I have updated my question . Hope so , it will help you to find solution regarding to my problem.

Comment: I don't know how wamp works. Can you check if the MySQL-Service is listed in your service snap-in?

Comment: I'm not really sure what other answer you expect form us, than what is written in the linked question. You must confirm the name of your mysql service and make sure that your code uses that name.

Answer (score 0):

> Start MYQSL

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
ServiceController controller  = new ServiceController();

controller.MachineName = ".";
controller.ServiceName = "mysql";

// Start the service
controller.Start();

// Stop the service
controller.Stop();
```